# LibCurl Usage: use libcurl form cannot upload file which is writing per 1ms

Tags: c++, http, curl, file-upload, webserver

When I use libcurl to post file to server, I met a confuse situation.

I cannot upload file that is writing, but the server returned 200.

for example, there is a shell bash that is writing per 1ms:

```
while true
do
        echo "test" >> newfile.log
        sleep 0.001

done
```

I have a c++ program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_mime *form = NULL;
    curl_mimepart *field = NULL;

    const char* path = argv[1];

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (NULL == curl) {
        return -1;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    struct curl_slist *headers = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Connection:close");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    /* Create the form */
    form = curl_mime_init(curl);

    field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
    curl_mime_name(field, "file");
    curl_mime_filedata(field, path);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1); 

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    std::cout << "http upload file perform ret:" << res << std::endl;
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }

    /* then cleanup the form */
    curl_mime_free(form);
    /* free slist */
    curl_slist_free_all(headers);

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  return 0;
}
```

and a server in python:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import uuid

app = Flask(import_name=__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/server/cloud'
# windows
# app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'D:/cloud/'

@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files.get('file')
    if file is None:
        return "file is null"
    
    file_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4()) 

    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "demo_file"))
    return file_uuid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8083)
```

Why it cannot upload the newfile.log when it is writing, could you help me?

Comment: Random guess: libCurl does not like the fact that you are changing the file size after a field.